# Does bearer token authentication work with Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false?

Tags: node.js, cors

My client sends requests authenticated via the following header:

```http
Authorization: Bearer some-token
```

Will including the following header in responses make things not work?

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
```

Comment: In your given example Font-end is not configure with XMLHttpRequest. As I am new to CORS I need basic understand at server side to prevent Bearer Token.

Comment: As frond-end javascript code is sending Bearer Authentication information in header to Server. Does CORS Credentials False can restrict that call ?

Comment: @esqew FWIW, the linked answer is outdated/misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that `false` isn't a valid value for the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header. [According to the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax), the only valid value is `true` (lowercase). Including one `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header in a response with a value other than `true` is functionally equivalent to altogether omitting that header from the response.

The question then becomes:

> Does `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` need to be present in responses to CORS requests for things to work?

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` is only required in responses to cross-origin *credentialed* requests, e.g. requests initiated from a different Web origin with

- [`withCredentials = true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials%5B) with the [`XmlHttpRequest` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or
- [`credentials: 'include'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#credentials) with [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

The term [*credentials*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#credentials), in this context, refers to browser-managed credentials or [*ambient authority*](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc6265.html#ambient-authority), i.e. things that the browser *automatically* attaches to requests (when applicable): cookies, client-side TLS certs, regular `Basic` auth, etc.

If your *client* includes an `Authorization` header (regardless of the authentication scheme used: `Basic`, `Bearer`, etc.) to an otherwise non-credentialed request, the presence of `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in the corresponding response is irrelevant. [This instance of Jake Archibald's CORS playground](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=POST&requestUseCORS=1&requestSendCredentials=&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&preflightAllowCredentials=&preflightAllowMethods=POST&preflightAllowHeaders=Authorization&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&responseAllowCredentials=&responseExposeHeaders=&requestHeaderName=Authorization&requestHeaderValue=Bearer+xxx) may be sufficient to convince you.

However, a necessary condition for things to work is that the response to the preflight request include an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header that lists, possibly among other request-header names, `Authorization` (case-insensitive), e.g.

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
```

---

### Addendum

According to [the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-non-wildcard-request-header-name), the `Authorization` request-header name is special insofar as it is not covered by the wildcard. For example, if you must allow request-header name `Authorization`, the following won't work in a compliant browser:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

Most browsers still do contravene the Fetch standard in this respect, but [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1176753) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1687364) have plans to remedy the situation.