# What does it mean to "send credentials" in the context of a JS HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, cors, cross-domain

I understand that there are several possible values for sending credentials including `same-origin`, `include`, and `omit`.  This can be found in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials) that is readily available.  I've reviewed the [fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-credentials-mode), but it's still not obvious to me what this means.

It is also associated with the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` [CORS header response](https://http.dev/access-control-allow-credentials), which I understand.  What I'm struggling with is what does this actually affect?

The above documentation indicates that it affects cookies, but it also hints at the possibility that it can also impact other components:

> (cookies, basic http auth, etc..)

Does it impact the `Authorization` header?  Does it affect all cookies or just credential carrying ones?  What else?

This is less than clear for me.  Is there documentation somewhere that tells me exactly what  the credentials setting impacts?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201271/does-bearer-token-authentication-work-with-access-control-allow-credentials-fal/76202037#76202037

Comment: That's really interesting, but still leaves me somewhat confused.  I wish he would've pointed to specific documentation describing it in reference format.

Comment: The de facto spec is [the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials), but it's difficult to read.