Authorization is not in the request headers
I'm trying to protect a page for authenticated users, but I came across an error where my back-end does not receive the cookies and authorization headers.
In searching for the error I found a method to solve it, using:
 headers: {
   Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
 }

But when I set the cookie in the back-end I use "httpOnly: true" for better security, so I can't access the token from the client side (front-end). That's why I configure "credentials: true" in both cors and axios so that in every request they automatically send the token
Cors Config (back-end):
const corsConfig = {
  origin: [process.env.BASE_URL],
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type"],
}

Axios Config (front-end):
const api = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: BASE_URL
})

Cookie JWT Auth middleware:
const cookieJwtAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    console.log(req.headers);
    const [, token] = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
    
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        statusCode: 401,
        message: "Token not found",
      });
    }
    const decodedToken = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);

    if (!decodedToken.username) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        statusCode: 401,
        message: "Username not found in token",
      });
    }

    req.user = decodedToken;
    next();

  } catch (err) {
    res.clearCookie("auth");
    return res.status(400).json({
      statusCode: 400,
      message: "Not authorized",
    })
  }
}

I noticed the error in the console.log line when the request through the front-end is different from the request through Insomnia
Note: When testing the route on Insomnia it works propretly
console.log(req.headers) - front-end:
{
  host: 'localhost:666',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es;q=0.6'
}

console.log(req.headers) - Insomnia:
{
  host: 'localhost:666',
  cookie: 'token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkVSSUNaQVJETyIsImlkIjoiMyIsImlhdCI6MTcxNDcwMDUzNiwiZXhwIjoxNzE0NzAwNTk2fQ.yo_H_yvxIQC1cwphXoXiVnOKWPNTL74dDS26gLgA9oc; auth=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkVSSUNaQVJETyIsImlkIjoiMyIsImlhdCI6MTcxNDc4MDQ1MiwiZXhwIjoxNzE0ODY2ODUyfQ.mTRXYF6O7fJEGvw8NqebbMy0q1SwUYRtKe0AIhVpyeQ',
  'user-agent': 'insomnia/9.1.0',
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkVSSUNaQVJETyIsImlkIjoiMyIsImlhdCI6MTcxNDc4MDQ1MiwiZXhwIjoxNzE0ODY2ODUyfQ.mTRXYF6O7fJEGvw8NqebbMy0q1SwUYRtKe0AIhVpyeQ',
  accept: '*/*'
}

I made several changes to the cors and axios settings thinking that this was the error. I Also tried adding to AllowedHeaders "Authentication" in Cors configuration
But I realized that the error was only in the front-end as it is not possible to use the split method if the value is undefined as in this case.
I still think it's just a small modification, but I still need a little help.
If you need more details about the problem or any part of the code, let me know in the comments

You need to list Authorization (not Authentication) as an allowed request-header name in your CORS configuration and you should be able to remove credentials: true; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201271/does-bearer-token-authentication-work-with-access-control-allow-credentials-fal/76202037#76202037

I tried as well too and I still don't get the headers correctly. I think this problem can be the way I set the cookie, idk

After so many attempts I started to check everything in the Inspect Tab on front-end (I don't know much about it and I started to delve deeper). So, when I set the cookie returns me an error:

This Set-Cookie header didn't specify a "SameSite" attribute and was
defaulted to "SameSite=Lax," and was blocked because it came from a
cross-site response which was not the response to a top-level
navigation. The Set-Cookie had to have been set with "SameSite=None"
to enable cross-site usage.

Apparently this new way how to set the cookie solved:
const token = jwt.sign({ username, id }, SECRET,{ expiresIn:'24h' })
res.cookie("auth", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None"
});

