Firebase v2 cors with credentials
Is there a means to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header to 'true' when using cors with firebase onRequest v2? I succeeded in making it work in v1, but not v2.
Below a description of my use case.
On the client side:
   fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:5001/backend/us-central1/cook`,
      {
        credentials: "include",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${authtoken}`,
        },
      }
    )

On the server side:
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import {onRequest as onRequestv1} from "firebase-functions/v1/https";

export const cook = onRequestv1(cookRoute); // works
export const cook = onRequest({cors: true}, cookRoute); // does not work

the v1 version of onRequest works ok (provided I set the HTTP headers properly in my cookRoute function). However, the v2 does not work (my cookRoute function is not even called), with error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.


You most likely don't need credentials: "include" if clients authenticate their requests by including an Authorization: Bearer ... header; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201271/does-bearer-token-authentication-work-with-access-control-allow-credentials-fal/76202037#76202037. Also, you don't need mode: "cors", since this is the default mode for cross-origin requests.

Thanks for the message. In my particular case, I don’t set the credentials for authentication but because the response includes a ‘set-cookie’ HTTP header (however mode is superfluous indeed)

News on this? I'm facing the very same issue

@OtaconKiko, I believe it is not possible as of today in v2. My solution is to stick to v1 for now.

@Vincent it's possible, I did it.

@OtaconKiko, in that case, could you please share how?
